# How do I import JSON files to firebase without importing manually

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Currently, to import bulk data to firebase, we have to go to our firebase console browse for json file and import it in. [e.g. of import button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8uCr.png)

However, I want to import it without going in to the console. 
That is, my system (web app) will allow admin to override all data in database with a default JSON file.

I don't think the Firebase API (https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html) provide such feature. Any recommendations?

Comment: did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Create a reference to the root of your database and simply set the JSON there.

```
firebase.database().ref().set({
  whatever: 'JSON'
});
```

This replaces everything that is currently in your database.

Comment: once json goes in to firebase, how do I get the API's to get/set/delete node?